# Page won't redirect after completing a form in an iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, iframe

I have a PHP script that isn't redirecting to another like it should. A user clicks a link and a [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) iframe is loaded, once the user clicks "Yes", the script is executed. The script successfully deletes the record from the database, however the record that was deleted remains on the page. Once the page is reloaded the deleted record disappears like it should.

So to give the impression that the record is deleted immediately, I figured a simple redirect back to the current tab they were on (see below) would work fine. However, even when I change the URL to something like `http://www.google.com`, the page never redirects after the MySQL is executed.

Here is the delete statement along with the header redirect. The variables are POST variables passed from another page. The  `$tab` variables are $_GET variables used to redirect the user back to the tab they are currently on.

```
if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM ". $name ." WHERE ". $id ." =  ". $record;
    $conn->exec($sql);
    header("Location: http://". $GlobalVARs->WebsiteENV() ."/lookup.php?t=". $tab);    
}
```

Here is the fancy box iframe & form that is being used to call the PHP block above.

```
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this row?</h3>
<form action="" method="POST">
        <input onclick="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="confirm" value="Yes">
        <input onclick="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();" class="btn btn-danger" value="No">
 </form>
```

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for the comment, I added an exit() and still got the same result.

Comment: Are you saying the iFrame doesn't reload like it should, or that you're for some reason is expecting the parent page to reload ?

Comment: I'm not on my comp to test but I want to say remove the action attribute completely from the form

Comment: Here's how you solve it -> `<input onclick="parent.jQuery.fancybox.close(); parent.location.reload()" class....`